# MySQL query not compiling with multiple AND operators

Tags: mysql

I've built this query in MySQL, however it is returning errors.  I've tried switching the <> operator to != and no luck, as well as changing the order of the AND operators.  I'm sure it is something simple, but I've been racking my brain with it!  If I remove the 'department NOT EQUAL to' condition it compiles, but it is important for it to be in there.

```
SELECT id,event,start_date,type, department
FROM eventmanager_events 
WHERE status='Scheduled' 
AND start_date > CURDATE() 
AND type='Conference' 
AND department<>'Human Resources' 
ORDER BY start_date
```

**EDIT**:  I've removed the 'type' condition, but it still will not compile properly.

**EDIT2**:  The error I receive, which I'm not sure why, is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Scheduled'
> AND start_date > CURDATE()
> AND type='Conference' at line 3

Comment: Are you sure problem in this condition: AND department<>'Human Resources' ? Can you provide dump?

Comment: Newness is a good enough reason!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c85e0/1

Comment: The only way I can get an error like that is if I leave out the `=` before `'Scheduled'`. Check the `WHERE` line carefully.

Comment: Check for hidden characters,retype the query again.

Comment: is "status" not a Mysql [keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/keywords-8-0.html)? Have you tried backticks around all column names or at least with "status"?

Answer (score 0):

What's the error ?

Dont use 'type'   , use smth elese

[Here](https://drupal.org/node/141051) is the lists of reserved keys in SQL

Well, you updated to Mysql , then 'type' is legal

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I've removed 'type' condition, but it still will not compile.

Comment: And from SELECT part too? You should escape it with backticks `` like \`type\`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to format your query to know which AND is standalone

```
SELECT id,event,start_date,type, department
    FROM eventmanager_events 
    WHERE status='Scheduled' 
        AND start_date > CURDATE() 
        AND type='Conference' 
        AND department<>'Human Resources' 
    ORDER BY start_date
```

Comment: What did you change other than indentation?